# Sorting two dimensional array of objects with status

Tags: arrays, algorithm, typescript, sorting

I have an array of objects with some status, like here.

```
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 0 0
x x x x x x
0 0 1 1 0 0
0 0 1 1 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

x is diff status of object, i want to change status to 2 for all 1 touching x and other 1 touching 1 touching x etc. So my result should look like this.

```
2 2 2 2 0 1
2 0 2 2 0 1
0 0 2 2 0 0
x x x x x x
0 0 2 2 0 0
0 0 2 2 0 0
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

Actually I would like to return array of objects which should change from 1 to 2.
I though about recursion function, function would check is touching object status equal to 1, if it is change status and do it for touching object with status 1. I cant imagine how this function may look, I never used recursion :/

If it matters I'm using TypeScript.

Your help will be Holy Grail for me.

Comment: How does sorting apply to the question? Explaining more about how this will be used could help pick better solutions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill) from `x` cells.

Recursive implementation is very simple (four-way connectivity):

```
Flood-fill (node, target-color, replacement-color):
 1. If target-color is equal to replacement-color, return.
 2. If the color of node is not equal to target-color, return.
 3. Set the color of node to replacement-color.
 4. Perform Flood-fill (one step to the south of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the north of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the west of node, target-color, replacement-color).
    Perform Flood-fill (one step to the east of node, target-color, replacement-color).
 5. Return.
```

but there are non-recursive implementations too.

Comment: You helped me second time, Thank you :)